# StateMachine Example Sifteo

Tags: c#, state-machine, sifteo

Can someone post a quick example (implementation) of the stateMachine? The concept is pretty easy but the SDK Documentation is a little fuzzy.

-- Initialize it, a few transitions with the iStateController with a cubes.... and finish the scene if your feeling frisky. Thanks

http://developer.sifteo.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created this implementation of a simple sifteo statemachine. It is rough, has problems and needs work, but the general concept is there. Please feel free to provide feedback on my sifteo game [ThreeCardMonte](https://github.com/cdesch/ThreeCardMonte)